# Horizontal scrolling control like the App store has

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I need a horizontal scrolling control like the App Store:

[image]

Should I use `UIScrollView` combined with `UIPageControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Yes, but I the problem is the same. In the view whitch controller should I use?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question. I think, implementing such a horizontal scrolling view should be straightforward with `UICollectionView`. Subclass `UICollectionViewController` and ``UICollectionViewCell`. Read the docs.

Comment: Now I'm tring to use this library: http://encryptedpixel.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/how-to-add-a-horizontal-scrolling-table-in-objective-c/

Comment: The article you are pointing to is quite outdated. In the meantime Apple has updated its API several times. Now there is `UICollectionView`, which is a native API by apple and solves not only horizontal Table Views but also collections like in iBook, which wrap to the next line. It is very similar to the `UITableView` logic, but more powerful and a bit more complex.

Comment: Ok thank you. Now I read some guidelines on uicollectionview.